# How to make a running flask on EC2 - allow access from outside?

Tags: python, node.js, flask, amazon-ec2

I am running Flask app on Linux EC2 with:

```
FLASK_APP=hello-flask.py FLASK_DEBUG=1 python -m flask run  --port 3000
```

It starts normally and I can ping it with `curl localhost:3000` and get response from flask.

However when going to `IP:3000` (ip of a server) - it denies access (error shows `connection refused`).

But when running e.g. NodeJS app on same port 3000 - I can access to it from outside (`IP:3000`).

What could be the problem with Flask?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer so just posting.. Should be added `--host=0.0.0.0` when starting the app.